# Mobile Site - How Do I Create a Cookie which remembers "Switch to Desktop" Site

Tags: mobile, cookies, mobile-website

I've optimised my site for mobile by including a seperate style sheet.
I have created a switch to desktop button which works perfectly using the code below.

```
$('#desktop-site-click').click(function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        document.cookie = 'cookiewidthset=yes'
        $('link[href="http://www.url.com/assets/style-mobile.css"]').prop('disabled', true);
        $('head').remove('<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>');
    });
```

This works but I need a way of creating a cookie so when the user navigates to another page the function above is remembered and they still see the desktop variant of the site.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assign the cookie path to the root, so that it applies to the whole site (root and descendants):

```
document.cookie = "cookiewidthset=yes; path=/";
```

> ;path=path (e.g., '/', '/mydir') If not specified, defaults to the current path of the current document location.
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/cookie